# @JsonProperty Required for Mapping Json File to POJO Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Java class file that looks like following:

```
public class ToBeMapped {
     String value1;
     int value 2;
}
```

Then I have a JSON file, named "test.json", looks like following:

```
{
    "value1": "hellow world",
    "value2": 12345
}
```

Then I try to map the JSON file to "TobeMapped" object in another Java file:

```
public class Testing {
    public void justTesting() throws IOException {
        ToBeMapped temp = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("path/to/test.json"), ToBeMapped.class);
    }
}
```

This will give me the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "value1" ...
```

If I add the `@JsonProperty` before each class variable as below, I can map the JSON file to the POJO without any errors.

```
public class ToBeMapped {

     @JsonProperty
     String value1;

     @JsonProperty
     int value 2;
}
```

Is it true that I have to add this header to each class variable in order for Jackson's mapper to map the JSON file/stream to the object?
Or I'm missing something in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Jackson will only use getters, setters and public fields to map Java objects to JSON and vice versa. You can either add the `@JsonProperty` annotation to every field you want to get mapped, or you can provide public getters and setters or you can use the `@JsonAutoDetect` annotation to tell Jackson to use the fields of your class:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

Providing public getters and setters and make your class a proper Java-bean should however be the preferred solution.

Comment: Great answer, although Jackson's auto-detection also uses `public` fields by default - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features

Comment: @ShmulikKlein thanks for the input. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will use the preferred solution.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Jackson's auto detection binds `public` fields and `public` setters for deserialization (converting the JSON representation into a Java object).

In your case, `value1` and `value2` visibility is `package-protected` and therefore aren't being auto-detect by Jackson.

You have a few options - you change their visibility to `public` or use `@JsonProperty` to help Jackson recognize them or you can change the `ObjectMapper` settings for auto detection to include `package-protected` fields:

- `ObjectMapper` configuration: `mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.NON_PRIVATE);`
- Class annotation: `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NON_PRIVATE)`

Answer (score 0):

I think they should be public or have setters. And you have typo in value 2 (cant use space)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need @JsonProperty, just add setters.

```
public class ToBeMapped {

    private String value1;
    private int value;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }
    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```